# Is "#define TYPE(x) typename decltype(x)" a bad idea?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, decltype, typename

Is it a bad idea to define

```
#define TYPE(x) typename decltype(x)
```

as a fast way to get the member type of the class of a variable in C++11?

Justification:

Consider the following (oversimplified) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define TYPE(x) typename decltype(x)

class A {
public:
  typedef int mtype;
  void set(mtype const& x) { foo = x; }
  mtype get() { return foo; }
private:
  mtype foo;
};

A make() { return A(); }

int main() {
  auto a = make();
  TYPE(a)::mtype b = 3;
  a.set(b);
  std::cout << a.get() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

That is, I have a class with some member type "mtype" and a function which returns me an instance of this class. Thanks to auto, I don’t have to worry about the name of the class as long as I know that my function does its job. However, at one point or another, I have to define a variable of a specific type, which, for convenience, has a typedef to "mtype" in my class.

If I only have the variable name "a" around but I know that this variable has this class, I can do

```
typename decltype(a)::mtype b;
```

to define a variable b of type A::mtype.

Is it now a bad idea to put this "typename decltype" into a macro? Are there obvious, common cases in which it will break? Is there a better way to quickly get at this type?

Bonus: "a::mtype" would be nicest - is there a reason it is not defined to behave as "decltype(a)::mtype" in the standard?

Comment: Having `typename` in your macro seems like a bad idea.  A partial statement being generated by a macro?  Ik.  Second, try it with a reference variable (oops).

Comment: Hmpf. Thanks for the pointer, though, I’ll stick to the long form then! (:

Comment: Why not simply use `auto b = 3;` ?

Comment: @Jarod42: "b" has, for example, type `std::array<std::vector<Rep>, rank>` where `rank` is a template parameter of `A`, `Rep` some custom type and I don’t have nice factory functions for this type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is bad. Use a [template-using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead:

```
template<class T>
using mtype_t = typename T::mtype;
```

Usage:

```
auto a = make();
mtype_t<decltype(a)> b = 3;
```

Comment: This is nearly as long as "typename decltype" and doesn’t seem to work with different member types (which the #define above doesn’t deal with at all and leaves to the user). But I get the hint that the macro is a bad idea (: